# Using Vaadin Flow with other servlets in Jakarta EE environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin-flow, payara, payara-micro

I would like to use the Vaadin Flow along with other servlets in Jakarata EE environment, but I can't to do so because Vaadin intercepts all requests to "/". I tried to add the following lines to the *application.properties* file as it was recommended here https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17374548/change-url-mapping-for-vaadin-flow-and-spring:

```
vaadin.urlMapping=/ui/* 
server.servlet.context-path=/
```

But it seems that the *application.properties* file is ignored when app is deployed as a war. Is there any way to map Vaadin to "/ui/" path in this case?

To be more specific, I am using the Payara Micro 5.2022.5 and the Vaadin Flow 23.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vaadin servlet is automatically deployed to the root of the application only if there isn't any manually deployed Vaadin servlet. You can thus manually configure the `com.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet` servlet for some other path in `web.xml` or create your own subclass with a custom mapping defined with the `@WebServlet` annotation.

The description you found with configuration through `application.properties` is only for use with Spring.